# Using typedef void* within a .dll

Tags: c++, verilator

I try to make a .dll from the Verialtor source code, since they've implemented this possibility.

They use a common handler `typedef void* svScope`
to initialize scopes. The .dll uses this handle aswell.
Now I'm able to create new functions using

`__declspec(dllexport) svScope svGetScope( void );`

Here's the header code svdpi.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_SVDPI
#define INCLUDED_SVDPI

#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) typedef void* svScope;

__declspec(dllexport) svScope svGetScope( void );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

And a simple implementation svdpi.cpp

```
#include "svdpi.h"

svScope svGetScope() {return 0;}
```

I've created the test file test.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "svdpi.h"

int main()
{
    svScope Scope = svGetScope();
}
```

I compiled the library and linked it. The compiler finds the library yet I get this error

g++ -o test.exe -s test.o -L. -lsvdpi

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_imp__svGetScope'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Typedefs are meaningful only in source code, they do not even exist in the binary once it is compiled (I believe)

Comment: Yeah but it ignores the dll attribute and therefore the functions are undefined when i build my programm.

Comment: Are the functions' declarations marked with the dll attribute? Because it won't transfer from the typedef to the function, even if the function uses the typedef.

Comment: The declaratrion looks like this: __declspec(dllexport) typedef void* svScope;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `XXTERN` on a function delcaration. You're not showing us any actual source code that contains functions that must be exported, but let's imagine this:

```cpp
svScope foo();
```

This function will return a `svScope`, which is just a `void *`. If you want it to be exported you must mark it so with `__declspec(export)` (or, in your case `XXTERN`:

```cpp
XXTERN svScope foo();
```

See [Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-160).

EDIT: After the question was edited.

In your DLL you need:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) svScope foo();
```

And in the application that uses the DLL you need:

```cpp
__declspec(dllimport) svScope foo();
```

Comment: yeah that's true
``XXTERN svScope svGetScope(void);``
That's the function where i get **undefined reference to `_imp__svGetScope**

Comment: It's true I didn't show you any meaningful code at all..

Comment: the .dll is also recognized and linked by the compiler so i don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You should edit your question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The actual error you get will also help.